# Plotly: How to inspect the basic figure structure (version 4)

Tags: python, plotly

For older versions of plotly, for example in Jupyterlab, you could simply run `figure` to inspect the basics of your figure like this:

**Ouput:**

```
{'data': [{'marker': {'color': 'red', 'size': '10', 'symbol': 104},
   'mode': 'markers+lines',
   'name': '1st Trace',
   'text': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
   'type': 'scatter',
   'x': [1, 2, 3],
   'y': [4, 5, 6]}],
 'layout': {'title': 'First Plot',
  'xaxis': {'title': 'x1'},
  'yaxis': {'title': 'x2'}}}
```

**Code for versions prior to V4:**

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[4,5,6], marker={'color': 'red', 'symbol': 104, 'size': "10"},
                    mode="markers+lines",  text=["one","two","three"], name='1st Trace')

data=go.Data([trace1])
layout=go.Layout(title="First Plot", xaxis={'title':'x1'}, yaxis={'title':'x2'})
figure=go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
#py.iplot(figure, filename='pyguide_1')
figure
```

If you do the same thing now with a similar setup, the same approach will not produce the figure basics, but rather plot the figure itself:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[4,5,6], marker={'color': 'red', 'symbol': 104},
                    mode="markers+lines",  text=["one","two","three"], name='1st Trace')  

figure = go.Figure(data=trace1)  

figure
```

**Output:**

[image]

In many ways this is  similar to how you for example would build and plot a figure with `ggplot` in `R`. And since plotly is available for both `R` and `Python` I thinks this makes sense after all. But I'd really like to know how to access that basic setup.

***What I've tried:***

I think this change is due to the fact that `figure` is now a `plotly.graph_objs._figure.Figure` and used to be a dictionary(?). So `figure['data']` and `figure['layout']` are still dicts with necessary and interesting content:

**Output from `figure['data']`**

```
(Scatter({
     'marker': {'color': 'red', 'symbol': 104},
     'mode': 'markers+lines',
     'name': '1st Trace',
     'text': [one, two, three],
     'x': [1, 2, 3],
     'y': [4, 5, 6]
 }),)
```

**Output from `figure['layout']`**

```
Layout({
    'template': '...'
})
```

And of course options such as `help(figure)` and `dir(figure)` are helpful, but produces a very different output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that 'forgetting' the brackets for `figure.show()` will give me exactly what I'm looking for. So with a setup similar to the code in the question and with plotly V4, simply running `figure.show` will give you this:

**Output:**

```
<bound method BaseFigure.show of Figure({
    'data': [{'marker': {'color': 'red', 'symbol': 104},
              'mode': 'markers+lines',
              'name': '1st Trace',
              'text': [one, two, three],
              'type': 'scatter',
              'x': [1, 2, 3],
              'y': [4, 5, 6]}],
    'layout': {'template': '...'}
})>
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[4,5,6], marker={'color': 'red', 'symbol': 104},
                    mode="markers+lines",  text=["one","two","three"], name='1st Trace')  

figure = go.Figure(data=trace1)  

figure.show
```