# Plotly: How to inspect and make changes to a plotly figure?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Related questions have already been asked and before e.g.

- [How can I search for the options for a particular property of a plotly figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560745/how-can-i-search-for-the-options-for-a-particular-property-of-a-plotly-figure)
- [Plotly: How to inspect the basic figure structure (version 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713125/plotly-how-to-inspect-the-basic-figure-structure-version-4)

But the answers to these questions have been limited by the fact that not all parameters have been available through Python, meaning that the real answers were buried somewhere in JavaScript. But for newer versions of plotly, how can you inspect and edit a plotly figure? How could you, for example, find out what the background color of a figure is? And then change it? From the second link above you can see that `fig.show` and `print(fig)` will reveal some details about the figure structure. But certainly not all of it. The code snippet below will produce the following plot:

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='Canada'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title='Life expectancy in Canada')
fig.show()
```

Running `fig.show` will now partly reveal the structure of the figure in the form of a dict:

```
<bound method BaseFigure.show of Figure({
    'data': [{'hovertemplate': 'year=%{x}<br>lifeExp=%{y}<extra></extra>',
              'legendgroup': '',
              'line': {'color': '#636efa', 'dash': 'solid'},
              'mode': 'lines',
              'name': '',
              'orientation': 'v',
              'showlegend': False,
              'type': 'scatter',
              'x': array([1952, 1957, 1962, 1967, 1972, 1977, 1982, 1987, 1992, 1997, 2002, 2007],
                         dtype=int64),
              'xaxis': 'x',
              'y': array([68.75 , 69.96 , 71.3  , 72.13 , 72.88 , 74.21 , 75.76 , 76.86 , 77.95 ,
                          78.61 , 79.77 , 80.653]),
              'yaxis': 'y'}],
    'layout': {'legend': {'tracegroupgap': 0},
               'template': '...',
               'title': {'text': 'Life expectancy in Canada'},
               'xaxis': {'anchor': 'y', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'title': {'text': 'year'}},
               'yaxis': {'anchor': 'x', 'domain': [0.0, 1.0], 'title': {'text': 'lifeExp'}}}
})
```

But as you can see for yourself, there are a lot of details missing. So how can you peform a more complete figure introspection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 4.10, the plotly developers have introduced the awesome `fig.full_figure_for_development()` function which they talk about [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-plotly-py-4-10-date-axis-improvements-a-faster-px-imshow-and-full-figures-for-development/44685). There you'll see that:

> `fig.full_figure_for_development()` function will return a new `go.Figure`
> object, prepopulated with the same values you provided, as well as all
> the default values computed by Plotly.js, to allow you to learn more
> about what attributes control every detail of your figure and how you
> can customize them. This function is named “for development” because
> it’s not necessary to use it to produce figures, but it can be really
> handy to explore figures while you’re figuring out how to build them.

So building on the example in the question, the following snippet will produce an output of about 180 lines containing, among a plethora of other details, this part about the figure layout:

```
'margin': {'autoexpand': True, 'b': 80, 'l': 80, 'pad': 0, 'r': 80, 't': 100},
'modebar': {'activecolor': 'rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.7)',
           'bgcolor': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
           'color': 'rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.3)',
           'orientation': 'h'},
'newshape': {'drawdirection': 'diagonal',
            'fillcolor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            'fillrule': 'evenodd',
            'layer': 'above',
            'line': {'color': '#444', 'dash': 'solid', 'width': 4},
            'opacity': 1},
'paper_bgcolor': 'white',
'plot_bgcolor': '#E5ECF6',
'separators': '.,',
'showlegend': False,
'spikedistance': 20,
```

And there you can also see the background color of the plot as `'plot_bgcolor': '#E5ECF6'`. And you probably know that you can *set* the background color using to for example `'grey'` using `fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='grey')`. But now you know how to *get* it as well:

```
# In:
fig.layout.plot_bgcolor

# Out:
'#E5ECF6'
```

And in knowing how to do this, you know how to get and set almost any attribute of a plotly figure. And it doesn't matter if you've built the figure using `plotly.graph_objects` or `plotly.express`