# Plotly: How to prevent varying thickness of bars in a Gantt diagram?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I'm trying to make a `plotly` [Gantt](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/) diagram using `plotly.express` as in the example, but `plotly` is somehow varying the bar thickness based on the given names (see picture, red > green > blue):

[image]

The code looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('stackoverflow.csv')
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource", text="Task", width=1600, height=800)
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="1000",
    tickformat="%M:%S",
    ticklabelmode="instant")
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[df.Start.min(), df.Finish.max()])
fig.show()
```

With `stackoverflow.csv` being:

```
Task,Start,Finish,Workstation,Resource
1,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:05.400,1,ABL
2,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,2,ABS
3,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,3,ABU
4,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,4,ACC
5,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,4,ACC
6,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,1970-01-01 01:00:05.300,4,ACC
7,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,5,ABS
8,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,6,ACT
9,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,7,ACC
10,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,7,ACC
11,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,1970-01-01 01:00:05.300,7,ACC
12,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,8,ABS
13,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,9,ABU
14,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,10,ACC
15,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,11,ABS
16,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,12,ABU
17,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,13,ACC
18,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,13,ACC
19,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,14,ABS
20,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,15,ABP
21,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.500,16,ABZ
22,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,17,ACC
23,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,17,ACC
24,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,18,ABS
25,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,19,AAW
26,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,20,ACC
27,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,20,ACC
28,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,21,ABS
29,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,22,ABU
30,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,23,ACC
```

I want all the bars to be of the same thickness, surprisingly this works when I change the names of the `Resource` to some random 3-char value:
[image]

I think it has to do with the resources starting with `AB*` or `AC*`. Unfortunately, the names of the resources depend on real-world names, so I cannot arbitrarily change them. The varying bar thickness happens as well when the name of the resource is something like `FooBar-Axx-FOO` with `xx = [CC, BS, CT...]`. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to prevent it?

P.S.: The

```
fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="1000",
    tickformat="%M:%S")
```

was necessary to show seconds in the Gantt instead of days... is there a better way to achieve this?

---

**Update**:
`conda` environment yaml file I'm using to create the problem:

```yaml
name: stack
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - pytorch
  - plotly
dependencies:
    - python>=3.5,<3.8
    - pandas
    - pip
    - pip:
      - plotly
```

slightly modified code still yielding the same problem as shown above:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from io import StringIO


csv = """Task,Start,Finish,Workstation,Resource
1,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:05.400,1,ABL
2,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,2,ABS
3,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,3,ABU
4,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,4,ACC
5,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,4,ACC
6,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,1970-01-01 01:00:05.300,4,ACC
7,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,5,ABS
8,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,6,ACT
9,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,7,ACC
10,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,7,ACC
11,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,1970-01-01 01:00:05.300,7,ACC
12,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,8,ABS
13,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,9,ABU
14,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,10,ACC
15,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,11,ABS
16,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,12,ABU
17,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,13,ACC
18,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,13,ACC
19,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,14,ABS
20,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,15,ABP
21,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.500,16,ABZ
22,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,17,ACC
23,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,17,ACC
24,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,18,ABS
25,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,19,AAW
26,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,20,ACC
27,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,20,ACC
28,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,21,ABS
29,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,22,ABU
30,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,23,ACC"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
# df = pd.read_csv("stackoverflow.csv")
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource", text="Task", width=1600, height=800)
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="1000",
    tickformat="%M:%S",
    ticklabelmode="instant")
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[df.Start.min(), df.Finish.max()])
fig.show()
```

The output of `conda list`:

```
pip                       20.2.4                     py_0    conda-forge
plotly                    4.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.8           h6f2ec95_1_cpython    conda-forge
```

Comment: Which Plotly version are you running? I'm on `'4.12.0'` and your code snippet does not produce that gantt diagram with the data sample you've provided.

Comment: @vestland tested it with `plotly` `4.11.0` and `4.12.0` both producing the plot above for me... Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Any ideas or hints for me?

Comment: I might even have a solution. But it worries me a bit that the code in your snippet does not produce the result you're showing. We can take a closer look at it together on chat. Perhaps sunday evening or monday.

Comment: It would help if you start a fresh python session, and run your code on the *exact* data sample that you have provided. Otherwise I'll have to spend too much time on recreating the problem rather than the solution itself.

Comment: It's really wondering that you don't get the same output... Will try it out a different way and let you know. Monday would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***(this is an answer in progress and prone to changes)***

---

#### A possible solution:

But only a *possible* solution since I'm still not able to reproduce your code snippet and corresponding plot 100%. But we'll take a closer look at that in the details. And you'll need the latest Plotly version and also Kaleido. But those are pretty straight forward installations and a huge step forward for plotly. In my humble opinion at least...

#### Code 0:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource", text="Task", width=1600, height=800)
f2 = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
f2.layout.barmode = 'group'
f2.show()
```

#### Plot 0:

[image]

---

#### The details:

---

We're going to have to do this step by step. Firstly, when I run your provided code, I'm getting this:

#### Plot 1:

[image]

#### Code 1:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from io import StringIO


csv = """Task,Start,Finish,Workstation,Resource
1,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:05.400,1,ABL
2,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,2,ABS
3,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,3,ABU
4,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,4,ACC
5,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,4,ACC
6,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,1970-01-01 01:00:05.300,4,ACC
7,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,5,ABS
8,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,6,ACT
9,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,7,ACC
10,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,7,ACC
11,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,1970-01-01 01:00:05.300,7,ACC
12,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,8,ABS
13,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,9,ABU
14,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,10,ACC
15,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,11,ABS
16,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,12,ABU
17,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,13,ACC
18,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,13,ACC
19,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,14,ABS
20,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,15,ABP
21,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.500,16,ABZ
22,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,17,ACC
23,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,17,ACC
24,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,18,ABS
25,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,19,AAW
26,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,20,ACC
27,1970-01-01 01:00:02.000,1970-01-01 01:00:03.300,20,ACC
28,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,21,ABS
29,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.000,22,ABU
30,1970-01-01 01:00:00.000,1970-01-01 01:00:01.300,23,ACC"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
# df = pd.read_csv("stackoverflow.csv")
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource", text="Task", width=1600, height=800)
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="1000",
    tickformat="%M:%S",
    ticklabelmode="instant")
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[df.Start.min(), df.Finish.max()])
fig.show()
```

In order to come close to your provided screenshot, I have to comment out a few lines as shown below. But it's still not the same figure as yours.

#### Plot 2:

[image]

#### Code 2 (same dataset):

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
# df = pd.read_csv("stackoverflow.csv")
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource", text="Task", width=1600, height=800)
# fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
# fig.update_xaxes(
#     dtick="1000",
#     tickformat="%M:%S",
#     ticklabelmode="instant")
# fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[df.Start.min(), df.Finish.max()])
fig.show()
```

I find that a bit weird. And the possible solution is even weirder. If you take a look at the post [Plotly: How to inspect and make changes to a plotly figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64653207/plotly-how-to-inspect-and-make-changes-to-a-plotly-figure) you'll see how you can reveal most of the figure attributes using `f2 = fig.full_figure_for_development`. Any changes you do to `f2` should also be possible to do to `fig`. But not in this case. In order to get a result that resembles your desired output, I had to do the following:

#### Code 3:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource", text="Task", width=1600, height=800)
f2 = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
f2.layout.barmode = 'group'
f2.show()
```

#### Plot 3:

[image]

Maybe we're getting somewhere here? But now you might think "why not `fig.layout.barmode = 'group'`?". Well, here's the result of that:

#### Plot 4:

[image]

#### Code 4:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource", text="Task", width=1600, height=800)
f2 = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
# f2.layout.barmode = 'group'
# f2.show()
fig.layout.barmode = 'group'
fig.show()
```

I find this whole thing to be more than a bit strange. But try please try it out and let me know how it all works out for you!

Comment: I posted an answer to your proposed solution, but it got deleted...

Comment: @Albo No worries. I can see it. But here's a very important detail. *My data* is really *your data*. So the question is; are *you* running the data you provided? And I see this all the time; users share a sample of their data that does not really represent, or is a ble to solve, their problem. So what you need to do now is to take sample `Code 0` from my answer and run it on your end and see if your output is the same as mine. If it it *is*, then something gets lost between your real world data and your provided sample. If it's *not*, then it has to be a plotly version probelm of some sort.

Comment: Already the thought occurred to me that I'm not using the same data you used, but since I explicitly designed this example to showcase the problem (and don't use it anywhere else) this shouldn't be a problem. Nevertheless, I double-checked the `csv` data and every time I *copied* the code you had here on stackoverflow (including the data).
I wrote the *exact* code I used to generate all the plots in my answer at the end of the post. Tried it now again with your `code 1` sample and copied it ... looks exactly like the plot I showed under `Code 1 - Plot 1`... I'm at loss here...

Comment: @Albo Ok. But that does not mean that the suggested solution will not work. Did you tro to build the figure using `full_figure_for_development()` and then set `layout.barmode = 'group'`

Comment: Yep, see `Code 5 - Plot 5`, it works. But I'm wondering why... Do you have any idea? Might have to do with something suggested under `Code 4`?

Comment: @Albo I'm wondering why too. But if it works, it works =)

Comment: I found some other examples where the `full_figure_for_development` is not helping anymore :(

Comment: @Albo Cool! Would you care to share your findings somehow? Perhaps write it up as a few questions?

Comment: Sure! Wrote you a chat message