# How to add a gap between specific bars in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have the following bar chart generated from `px.bar(...)` with Plotly Express:
[image: Bar chart]

I'd like to add a vertical gap between the 10 and "All" bars to differentiate the "All" bar. Is there a way to do this in Plotly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge there's no direct way to do this. As an alternative solution I would consider splitting the data and setting your figure up as two [subplots](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/). You'll need to add some customization like `shared_xaxes=True` and adjust row heights to suit your use case through `row_heights=[0.2, 0.8]`. Using the built-in dataset `px.data.tips` the snippet below uses an approach like this to produce the following plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from itertools import cycle

df = px.data.tips()

fig1 = px.bar(df[df.day != 'Sun'], x="total_bill", y="day", orientation='h')
fig2 = px.bar(df[df.day == 'Sun'], x="total_bill", y="day", orientation='h')

f = fig2.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, row_heights=[0.2, 0.8])
fig.update_layout(template = 'plotly_white')
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid = False)

fig.add_traces(fig2.data, 1, 1)
fig.add_traces(fig1.data, 2,1)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @vestland! I'm not sure what `cycle` and `full_figure_for_development` are doing, but this solution worked for me, after playing around with `vertical_spacing` and other styling arguments.

Comment: @N.Woodruff Happy to help! Take a look at my recent question [How to apply a counter or index elements using a lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68846192/how-to-apply-a-counter-or-index-elements-using-a-lambda-function) for more info on `cycle`. `fig.full_figure_for_development` isn't necessary for the solution, but an ***excellent*** way to [explore plotly figure objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64653207/plotly-how-to-inspect-and-make-changes-to-a-plotly-figure).